# Bitwise Operations On Large Strings In PHP

Tags: php, 32bit-64bit, bitwise-operators

Here's my problem.  I'm currently trying to implement a few Cryptography standards in PHP for compatibility reasons.  The one I'm working on now is SHA256 and SHA512.  They are both reasonably straight forward standards, and I'm not having an issue with that.

However, SHA512 requires bitwise operations on 64 bit integers.  Since PHP can have only 32 bit integers (with the compile), that leaves me with a problem.  How do I implement the bitwise functions necessary (modulo, shift, rotate, add, xor, and, or, etc) so that I both maintain compatibility and a reasonable level of performance...

I know for some of them implementing the functions is trivially done with 2 32 bit ints.  However, how will that work for `shift` and `rotate`?

What I've thought of doing is storing the strings in binary form (as a string of `01010`).  That way all bitwise operations will be completely architecture independent.  But this will likely cause a massive performance drop since they are used incredibly frequently in the standards (and in other parts of the library).

So my question is thus:  How can I easily allow for at least 64 bit string operations in a 32 bit compile of PHP while still maintaining a reasonable level for performance for every step...?

Oh, and my aim is portability here, so no extensions.  Other libraries I'll consider, but they must be portable...

Comment: You can treat a 64-bit number as two 32-bit numbers and juggle the "carry" part across the two numbers.

Comment: @Sal: sure.  But that's kind of a PITA.  I guess if it's the best I can do, so be it.  But if there's a cleaner way, I'm all ears...

Comment: Generalize the functionality by creating an "BitString" object that is just a wrapper for array of Ints w/ some bitwise functions that do what Salman talks about.

Comment: @Kendall: I would, except it appears that PHP's bitwise functions are arithmetic as opposed to logical.  So `0xFFFFFFFF >> 4 === 0xFFFFFFFF`.  So even ints won't work properly without some massive reworking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing the values in strings is really the right way to go.

But instead of storing 1's and 0's, just store 8 bits in every byte. It will still be easy to extract parts of the integer from your string.  You do need to manually do all operations such as shifting.

Comment: Well, the only reason I thought of storing 0 and 1 in a string is that it's trivial to implement each bitwise operator then.  (left shift is just appending a 0, right is just removing a trailing digit, etc)...

Comment: But it won't be very fast though.. If you do it binary, and extract parts per-byte (or per 32 bit even) you can still use the standard bitwise operators, but you need to make sure yourself things like a left-shift carries on to the next couple of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly there is no way to use the native data structure that represents ints given your environment and so you have to use a data structure on top. This will mean of course that you will not be able to apply your example given ... 0xFFFFFFFF >> 4 but you could use mystruct(0xFFFFFFFF) >> 4 (mystruct being the data structure defined by you).

If this sounds like a plan let me know and maybe I can help you with the rest of the solution.

Comment: considering PHP doesn't allow overriding operators (nor true structures), I'm not sure if that'll work.  If you know of a way in PHP to do so, I'm all ears...

Comment: when talking about data structures I was thinking of a class instance, however, unlike ocaml et al you are correct - overriding operators is not possible. :-(